# Extended Events for tracing deletes on specific table

Tags: sql-server, database

I tried to create an extended event using sql_statement_completed, I put two filters, one for the db name and the other for the object id of the table that I want to trace.

I put the event to run and then I perform and update on that specific table but nothing happened, is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

I'm using SQL Server 2014

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object_id of the sp_statement_completed event is the id of the stored procedure.

Do do this with XEvents, you'd have to parse the query text, which would be expensive and unreliable, or examine the query execution plans, which is expensive and difficult.

You probably want to use [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2014) or a [Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).